# Re-entering France on a French D-category intern visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I recently finished my 6-month internship in France and came back to India. My internship visa is still valid until September, and I have the OFII permit all done. Can I re-enter France on this visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can re-enter France as long as your visa remains valid (and with the OFII stamp in your passport that lets you leave and return).